# Can I recover data from a partially RAID 1 system?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid, data-recovery

I recently bought two 1TB HDDs because I wanted to build a RAID 1 system. I didn't want to lose 1TB of space so using the Windows 7 disk management I mirrored 700GB and kept the rest as a simple volume. So now I have a 700GB mirrored volume and 2 250GB simple volumes. Was it a good idea? If one disk fails will I be able to recover the data from the second one?

Comment: Don't look at it as "losing" 1TB of space. Look at it as having a mirror copy of your precious 1TB of data!

Comment: @LordPeter You're right. Now that I reconsidered my thinking I'm going to fully utilize the 2 disks as a RAID 1 system. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd only be able to to recover the data from the 700GB partition (being mirrored across both disks). Neither of the 2x250GB partitions could be recovered if lost (assuming you don't have anything else backing them up).

Note: I haven't used the RAID capabilities built into Windows before, but I don't see why it would be different to RAID in general.

Comment: If one disk fails I will still be able to access the 250GB partition of the other one right?

Comment: Yes, if one disk fails you would lose the 250GB partition stored on it and one of the copies of the 700GB (but that data will be on the other drive still). So you would only lose 250GB of data in total from a single disk failure.